# Bash: arithmetic addressed by line number and column

Tags: bash, awk

I have normally done this with Excel, but as I am trying to learn bash, I'd like to ask for advice here on how to do so. My input file resembles:

```
@       s0      legend  "1001"
@       s1      legend  "1002"
@target G0.S0
@type xy
2.0     -1052.7396157664
2.5     -1052.7330560932
3.0     -1052.7540013664
3.5     -1052.7780321236
4.0     -1052.7948229060
4.5     -1052.8081313831
5.0     -1052.8190310613
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
2.0     -1052.5384564253
2.5     -1052.7040374678
3.0     -1052.7542803612
3.5     -1052.7781686744
4.0     -1052.7948927247
4.5     -1052.8081704241
5.0     -1052.8190543049
&
```

where the above only shows two data sets: s0 and s1. In reality I have 17 data sets and will combine them arbitrarily. By combine, I mean I would like to:

1. For two data sets, extract the second column of each separately.
2. Subtract these two columns row by row.
3. Multiply the difference by a constant, $C.

> Note: $C multiplies very small numbers and the only way I could get it to not divide by zero was to take a massive scale.

---

**Edit:** After requests, I was apparently not entirely clear what I was going for. Take for example:

```
set0
2   x
3   y
4   z
set1
2   r
3   s
4   t
```

I also have defined a constant C.

I would like to perform the following operation:

```
C*(r - x)
C*(s - y)
C*(t - z)
```

I will be doing this for sets > 1, up to 16, for example (set 10) minus (set 0). Therefore, I need the flexibility to target a value based on its line number and column number, and preferably acting over a range of line numbers to make it efficient.

---

So far this works:

```
C=$(echo "scale=45;x=(small numbers)*(small numbers); x" | bc -l)

sed -n '5,11p' input.in | cut -c 5-20 > tmp1.in
sed -n '15,21p' input.in | cut -c 5-20 > tmp2.in
pr -m -t -s tmp1.in tmp2.in > tmp3.in
awk '{printf $2-$1 "\n"}' tmp3.in > tmp4.in
```

but the multiplication failed:

```
awk '{printf "%11.2f\n", "$C"*$1 }' tmp4.in > tmp5.in
```

returning:

```
       0.00
       0.00
       0.00
       0.00
       0.00
       0.00
       0.00
```

---

I have a feeling the whole thing can be accomplished more elegantly with awk. I also tried this:

```
for (( i=0; i<=6; i++ ))
do

n=5+$i
m=10+n

awk 'NR==n{a=$2};NR==m{b=$2} {printf "%d\n", $b-$a}' input.in > temp.in
done
```

but all I get in temp.in is a long column of 0s.

---

I also tried

```
awk 'NR==5,NR==11{a=$2};NR==15,NR==21{b=$2} {printf "%d\n", $b-$a}' input.in > temp.in
```

but got the error

```
awk: (FILENAME=input.in FNR=20) fatal: attempt to access field -1052
```

---

Any idea how to formulate this with awk, and if that doesn't work, then why I cannot multiply with awk above? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal input and state an output required for that. The output needed for your input is not clear

Comment: State your expected output at each steps for us to work it out!

Comment: Stop. A shell (e.g. bash) is an environment from which to call tools and manipulate files and processes with a language to sequence those calls. It is **not** a tool to manipulate text. The general purpose UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk so a "shell script" to manipulate text (as you are trying to write) would simply be the shell calling awk once. [edit] your question to state the expected output given your input file and explain the mapping between them so we can help you. You are mixing up shell syntax (`$a`) with awk syntax (`a`) for getting the value of variables in your awk script.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the error in terminology @EdMorton, and thank you for the correction. Do you mean it was inaccurate to begin my question with Bash:? I can edit that out. As for the output, as you saw the values are quite large, and $C itself is a massive number. I don't actually have the answer I am looking for, so I don't know what's "correct." I will however do my best to edit in something else to make it more clear what I am going for.

Comment: No, I just mean your approach of using a bunch of seds, cuts, prs, and then awk is wrong - the whole thing should simply be an awk script. No, I don't see the values are quite large and that wouldn't matter anyway - just tell us a value of C and post the output you expect given that input and that C value. If you don't know what the output should be how can you (or we) write a script to produce it?

Comment: I had the feeling it should be just in awk, which is why I made the effort in the second half to show my attempts to only do it in awk for correction. This thread so far has been quite helpful in pointing out mistakes in my perception on awk. I included the non-awk way exactly to try and show what I was going for, as they correctly lead to my goal. Did the edit in help at all to clarify things? As for C, it currently runs to 45 figures... My reason for not dumbing it down to simple proxy numbers was so that responses could correct me if one of my errors stemmed from a scale=45 number.

Comment: No you STILL haven't posted the expected output for any given sample input so you still haven't provided something we could simply test a potential solution against. Have you tried any of the solutions posted so far. Do any of them do what you want? If not, in what way do they not produce the expected output (whatever that is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does the math in one go

```
$ awk -v c=1 '/^&/ {s++} 
              s==1 {a[$1]=$2} 
              s==3 {print $1,a[$1],$2,c*(a[$1]-$2)} 
           /@type/ {s++}' file

2.0 -1052.7396157664 -1052.5384564253 -0.201159
2.5 -1052.7330560932 -1052.7040374678 -0.0290186
3.0 -1052.7540013664 -1052.7542803612 0.000278995
3.5 -1052.7780321236 -1052.7781686744 0.000136551
4.0 -1052.7948229060 -1052.7948927247 6.98187e-05
4.5 -1052.8081313831 -1052.8081704241 3.9041e-05
5.0 -1052.8190310613 -1052.8190543049 2.32436e-05
```

you can remove the decorations and add print formatting easily.  The magic numbers `1=g1` and `3=2*g2-1` correspond to data groups 1 and 2 as the order presented in the data file, can be converted to `awk` variables as well.

The counter `s` keeps track of whether you're in a set or not, Odd numbers correspond to sets and even numbers between sets.  The increment is done both at the start pattern and end pattern.  The order of increment statements were set in such a way they, they are not printed following the pattern (unset first, print set values, reset last}.  You can change the order and observe the effects.

Comment: This worked great when I tested it. I have a couple questions on the process if you don't mind. The /^&/ is a pattern searching for lines beginning with &, correct? s++ is a counter that increases s in increments of 1? Why doesn't /^&/ place me at line 12 in my input, and s++ count up from there (which is not line 5)? I guess I am confused how s==1 references the first data set, and how s==3 references the second data set. I would have thought one begins with /@type/ and goes up incrementally until /^&/.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[@&]/ { lineNr=0; next }
{
    ++lineNr
    if (lineNr in prev) {
        print $1, c * ($2 - prev[lineNr])
    }
    prev[lineNr] = $2
}

$ awk -v c=100000 -f tst.awk file
2.0 20115.9
2.5 2901.86
3.0 -27.8995
3.5 -13.6551
4.0 -6.98187
4.5 -3.9041
5.0 -2.32436
```

Comment: Dear drive-by downvoter - care to explain the downvote and delete vote?

Answer (score 0):

In your first try, you should replace that line:

```
awk '{printf "%11.2f\n", "$C"*$1 }' tmp4.in > tmp5.in
```

with that one:

```
awk -v C=$C '{printf "%11.2f\n", C*$1 }' tmp4.in > tmp5.in
```

You are mixing notations of bash shell with notation with awk.

- in shell you define variable without `$`, and you use them with `$`.
- Here you are in awk script, there is no `$` to use variables. Yet there are some special variables : $1 $2 ...
- You have put single quote ' around your awk script, so the shell variables cant be used. I mean you have written `$C`, but the shell can not see it inside single-quote. That is why you have to write `awk -v C=$C` so that the shell variable `$C` is transferred to an awk variable called `C`.

In your other tries with awk, we can see such errors also. Now I think you'll make it.